# How can I "SELECT out" multiple differently-defined rows from a large join table without re-defining it for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres.

What I have right now is like this:

```
SELECT <statement> FROM (
<MASSIVE JOIN STATEMENT>
)
UNION ALL
SELECT <different statement> FROM (
<SAME MASSIVE JOIN STATEMENT>
)
```

What I would really like is to have is a way to accomplish the same thing without having to put in the same massive join statement multiple times. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank You!!

I tried giving the table an alias and referencing the alias in the second SELECT statement, but it didn't work. Postgres says the relation does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given its the same source for both selects, have you tried using a CTE?

e.g:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  -- Your MASSIVE JOIN STATEMENT here
)

SELECT <statement> FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT <different statement> FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table VIEW for the massive SELECT.

However inspect the massive SELECT. In a similar case I had an outer join that could be simplified by a GROUP BY. That would be lucky though.

As you are doing ... UNION ALL ..., you probably have SELECT 1, ... UNION ALL SELECT 2, ... too. Maybe some of the joins are just for references.

Not a very satisfactory answer but the question seems to indicate that a simplification should be possible rather than a super pivot table or stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is by wrapping your original query in a subquery and then selecting from it in the UNION ALL part, you can get it working.

```sql
SELECT <statement>
FROM (
  SELECT <columns>
  FROM (
    -- your massive join statement goes here
    -- you can also include any filters or conditions you need
    SELECT <columns>
    FROM <your_tables>
    WHERE <your_conditions>
  ) AS subquery1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT <different statement>
  FROM (
    -- the same massive join statement
    SELECT <columns>
    FROM <your_tables>
    WHERE <your_conditions>
  ) AS subquery2
) AS combined_query;
```

This avoids repeating the massive join statement while achieving the desired outcome